# JavaScript String replace vs replaceAll

Tags: javascript, string, replaceall, ecmascript-2021

ECMAScript 2021 has added a new String function `replaceAll`.
A long time ago in a galaxy not so far away, people used `split` + `join` or regular expressions to [replace all occurences of a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1144783/how-to-replace-all-occurrences-of-a-string-in-javascript).

I created the following example to compare the new method to the old ones.
While I could see some differences in the first case, for example I can't use [replacement patterns](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replaceAll#specifying_a_string_as_a_parameter) with `split` + `join` or I need to escape special chars with `RegExp(str,"g")`, I can't see any difference in the second case.

What are the differences between the new method and the old ones (behaviour difference, performance, browser compatibility...) ?

```js
const source = "abcdefabcdef";
const str1 = "abc", str2 = "xyz";
const reg1 = /abc/g, reg2 = "xyz";

//Case 1 : When we want to replace a string by another
console.log(source.split(str1).join(str2));
console.log(source.replace(new RegExp(str1,"g"),str2));
//versus
console.log(source.replaceAll(str1,str2));

//Case 2 : When we want to use a regular expression
console.log(source.replace(reg1,reg2));
//versus
console.log(source.replaceAll(reg1,reg2));

//Result = "xyzdefxyzdef"
```

Comment: If I remember correctly this method was mainly added to catch the mistake of _not_ adding the `g` flag earlier (i.e. it's an actual runtime error, vs  logic error that might or might not present itself when the code runs). Browser support: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replaceAll#browser_compatibility . It's also much more explicit than `replace` with a `g`-flagged regex.

Comment: Please ask only 1 question.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

From gleaning the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replaceAll) for `replaceAll`, we find the following tidbits:

> const newStr = str.replaceAll(regexp|substr, newSubstr|function)

> Note: When using a `regexp` you have to set the global ("g") flag; otherwise, it will throw a TypeError: "replaceAll must be called with a global RegExp".

In other words, when calling `replaceAll` with a regex literal or `RegExp`, it must use the global flag.  So, there doesn't seem to be much gained by calling `replaceAll` versus just using the current `replace`.  However, one difference with `replaceAll` is that when passing it a string, it will automatically do a global replacement.  This is where you might save yourself a bit of typing, by not having to enter a global flag.

Comment: I started learning Javascript only after I had a reasonable grasp of PHP. For a really long time, I was continually caught out that `myString.replace('apples', 'oranges')` is _not_ the equivalent of `str_replace('apples', 'oranges', $My_String)` (because the PHP function is a _global_ string replace, like `replaceAll` but unlike `replace`).