# How to replace more than one word at one time in javascript

Tags: javascript

The `.replace(/\w+/g), function)` works well when replacing one single word inside `standardizeMap`, however, it fails when it comes to multiple words.

Sample input (Case 1):

```js
const standardizeMap = new Map([
    ["Hello world", "How are you"],
    ["apple pen", "appleP"],
    ["Swaziland", "Eswatini"])
"Hello world I have an apple pen in Swaziland".replace(/\w+/g, (word) =>
        standardizeMap.get(word) ? standardizeMap.get(word) : word
      )
```

Output:

```
Hello world I have an apple pen in Eswatini
```

Expected output:

```
How are you I have an appleP in Eswatini
```

Sample input (Case 2):

```
"Hello world I have an apple penin Swaziland".replace(/\w+/g, (word) =>
        standardizeMap.get(word) ? standardizeMap.get(word) : word
      )
```

Expected output:

```
How are you I have an apple penin Eswatini
```

How can I achieve it?

Comment: Does https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replaceAll help?

Comment: You should check what is the value of `word` in the callback function to understand the issue. :)

Comment: `"Hello world"` has a space in it, but `\w` won't match a space.

Comment: no. @evolutionxbox

Comment: oh, so using `replace()` is not possible to solve this problem? @Amessihel

Comment: You're not looking at the problem from the right angle. :)

Comment: I posted an answer, but its main point is that you need first to understand what's happening when the code is run.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calling `String.replace(/\w+/g, (word) => doStuff())` (or replaceAll, [same thing except that replaceAll requires the 'g' flag](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67296735/4375327)) will let the method perform the replacement for each matching sequences of `\w+`. You can see them using the console logging:

```
>> let text = "Hello world I have an apple pen in Swaziland";
>> text.replace(/\w+/g, function(word) {console.log(word);return word});
Hello
world
I
have
an
apple
pen
in
Swaziland
```

So, you should loop over your map and for each entry, replace in the text all occurrences of its key to its value.

Instead, you should loop through your map and, for each entry, replace in the text all occurrences of the entry's key with its value, as shown below for example.

```
let text = "Hello world I have an apple pen in Swaziland" ;
for (const [key, value] of standardizeMap) {
    text = text.replaceAll(key, value);
}
```

Comment: thank you, `s.get(key)` can be replaced by `value` right?

Comment: @TungTung, I've edited my answer.

Comment: can `value` replace `standardizeMap.get(key)`?

Comment: @TungTung, it can and it should. :D Edited answer, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

It might be better if you worked the other way around.  Loop thru the Map and replace whole words found in the text matching the item in the Map:

```js
const standardizeMap = new Map([
  ['Hello world', 'How are you'],
  ['apple pen', 'appleP'],
  ['Swaziland', 'Eswatini'],
])

let text1 = 'Hello world I have an apple pen in Swaziland'
let text2 = 'Hello world I have an apple penin Swaziland'

function replaceText(text, map) {
  for (let [key, value] of map) {
    let re = new RegExp(`\\b${key}\\b`, 'g')
    text = text.replace(re, value)
  }

  return text
}

console.log(replaceText(text1, standardizeMap))
console.log(replaceText(text2, standardizeMap))
```

Comment: Putting word breakers `\b` is a good idea, indeed.

Answer (score 1):

You need to iterate over each key value in `standardizeMap` and replace all occurrences of the key.

```
const standardizeMap = new Map([
  ["Hello world", "How are you"],
  ["apple pen", "appleP"],
  ["Swaziland", "Eswatini"],
]);

const input = "Hello world I have an apple pen in Swaziland";

function replaceString(map, input) {
  let output = input;
  for (const [key, value] of map) {
    output = output.replace(key, value);
  }
  return output;
}

console.log(replaceString(standardizeMap, input));
```